# Connection between Bootstrap componments reactstrap and react.Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to Rect. I'd like to ask perhaps a most basic question since I can't find the relavent documentation or a answer on Google.
Following is the first 3 lines of typical react code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {                                            
  Button,
  Modal,
} from "reactstrap";    
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
...
}
```

What is the connection between Bootstrap componments imported on the second line from reactstrap and the Component class in react(that is, react.Component)? Why a CustomModal subclass from react.Component instead of reactstrap.Modal? is react.Component a sort of abstract class and reactstrap.Modal concret class extending react.Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes. You extend React.Component to create your own custom class-based React components. The others that you are importing are from libraries where the library author has already created the components. Note that you can also create custom function-based React components where you don't extend React.Component.  I would recommend reading through the [React.Component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

To your question about how it relates to CustomModal, you would use Modal as a component within CustomModal.  For example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {                                            
  Button,
  Modal,
} from "reactstrap";    
export default class CustomModal extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return <Modal />;
    }
}
```

Note that this example is just to give you the idea of how to use an imported component in your own custom component.  It is not necessarily how to use `reactstrap.Modal` itself.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. More detail (such as pseudo code) depicting how a "class CustomModal extends Component" is connected to reactstrap.Modal will be helpful.

Comment: @techie11 They aren't necessarily connected. `reactstrap.Modal` could very well be a function component.  If it is a class component then it would also do just what you've seen - it would extend `React.Component`. The important thing to understand here is that with `reactstrap.Modal` you just don't need to worry about it.  The implementation details have been taken care of for you by the author.  You just need to import it and start using it (see my answer edit).  --IF-- it is a class component, then somewhere in its src code you would find `export default class Modal extends Component {...}`.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!